# Python LDAP search not returning ActiveDirectory attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, active-directory, ldap

When running an ldap search against an ActiveDirectory user, I only get back a subset of the attributes (verified by viewing the same user in Active Directory Explorer).

Is there any way to view these missing attributes, or is this a limitation of the ldap module?

```
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
search_filter = '(cn=foouser)'
base_dn = 'DC=foo,DC=bar,DC=net'

ldap_connection.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
ldap_connection.simple_bind_s(bind_dn, bind_password)

try: 
  result = ldap_connection.search_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, search_filter)
  pp.pprint(result)
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
  print e
finally:
  ldap_connection.unbind_s()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify which attributes to return, it will return all non-constructed attributes that have values. So you should be getting everything.

Constructed attributes are ones like `canonicalName`, `msDS-PrincipalName` and others. If you want to get those from the search, you need to specify those in the `attrlist` parameter of [`search_s`](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#ldap.LDAPObject.search). But once you specify *anything* in `attrlist`, then you need to specify *every* attribute you want to see.

Note that no matter what you specify, you will never see attributes that don't have values. You won't see it with a null value, you just won't see it at all.

Comment: I have a similar issue, I can't get `division` attribute and I checked it, it has value. I can get all other attributes, except this.

Comment: @Azize Are you reading from the Global Catalog (port 3268/3269)? Because the [`division`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-division) attribute isn't replicated to the GC.